# Can we use selenium for testing desktop applications?

Tags: automation, robotframework, ui-automation

I am testing a **WEB** and **Desktop** application (cross OS application: Windows - Mac - Linux) and I'm using **RobotFramework** to automate the tests.

For the Web I use **SeleniumLibrary** and it works perfectly .
**For code reuse reasons**, is it possible to use SeleniumLibrary to do the automatic tests for the Desktop application ?
Is it possible to interact SeleniumLibrary with desktop application elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeleniumLibrary works on the web so you can't reuse the code for a Desktop App test.

For GUI Apps I suggest you looking to [AutoitLibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary) or [ZoombaLibrary](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba)

Comment: I have a desktop application based on Electron (with Electron we can build cross-platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS) . 
So I think there is a way to use SeleniumLibrary to do the automatic tests for the Desktop application.

Comment: On MS Windows, Power Automate Desktop is now an option. I'm not sure, but it may come installed by default on some Win 11 machines.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible.
For desktop applications testing you can use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

However for pywinauto you will need to use your custom libraries. You can have a look at [Robtot framework custom libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries)

Comment: I also thought at first that it is impossible to automate tests for a desktop application using Selinium, but I found this: [link](https://confengine.com/conferences/selenium-conf-2016/proposal/2292/breaking-down-the-barriers-testing-desktop-apps-with-selenium) .
That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's _impossible_, but it would require work to make sure you sets of keywords that work in each environment. It would be work but it wouldn't be impossible.